# Loopback Node :- Error: Cannot find module 'enum'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I have searched a lot for the solution but not succeed

I Tried

```
   1.npm cache clean --force
   2.npm install
```

And also tried with

```
    1. Manually remove cache files from C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
    2. npm install OR npm install enum
```

I am facing this issue while running my node server on a laptop

it's showing an error in Console-like

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'enum'
Require stack:
- D:\project\server\utilities\NotificationManager.js
- D:\project\server\models\UserProjectAction.js
- D:\project\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\require.js
- D:\project\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js
- D:\project\node_modules\loopback-boot\index.js
- D:\project\server\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\server\utilities\NotificationManager.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\server\models\UserProjectAction.js:5:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\project\\server\\utilities\\NotificationManager.js',
    'D:\\project\\server\\models\\UserProjectAction.js',
    'D:\\project\\node_modules\\loopback-boot\\lib\\require.js',
    'D:\\project\\node_modules\\loopback-boot\\lib\\compiler.js',
    'D:\\project\\node_modules\\loopback-boot\\index.js',
    'D:\\project\\server\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

I am new in node js so not able to understand what exactly going wrong here.

Please help me to understand .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar kind of issue .And i resolved that by following these steps

```
1. Remove 'package-lock.json' file locally from your machine
2. 'run npm install' on project CMD command panel
```

I hope this can help you to resolve this issue.